# Implementing my own IXmlSerializer for a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-serialization, asmx

I'm making an asmx web service that passes a couple of objects, I have two issues with that: the first is that I use a dictionary and the second is that some of the objects have read only properties.

I've made enough compromises with the web service and I'm not going to give him the joy of winning another battle so I've decided to write my own serializer for my objects. Is that a good decision? I'm talking about 7 classes and one dictionary that all  have some sort of a read only property.
Do I have to make a schema file for each class? And looking at the IXmlSerializer implementation it doesn't seem too complicated, all I have to do is write a "constructor" for the class in ReadXml and a "deconstructor" in WriteXml, No?

**Edit:** Okay, that answers one question, now when I get the objects in the client they are received as a Dataset[], how do I convert them to the appropriate class?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use WCF? Spending all this trouble on ASMX services doesn't make much sense if you can avoid it.

Comment: Yes, there is one very big reason. This is a school project, and not only am I very time limited but I'm pretty sure I'm graded on my ability to use this exact technology...

Comment: good luck at the "School for Obsolete Technologies"...

Comment: @John, not only that. We have a unit in "Internet" which up until TWO years ago (when I did it) meant writing a site in CLASSIC ASP. Yes I do mean that version that everyone stopped using in 2002.  Only the year after us started using ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Overall you are right it is not very complicated for a given single class.

Where it can get complicated is if you have a full object graph as you describe. You just have to come up with an XML structure that contains all the information you need to construct an instance of your type and all dependent types.

This might require changes in your classes as well to work, i.e. if an instance of a dependent type is usually internally constructed by your main class, how to you construct this instance now externally and inject it into your class? Not pretty - So if there is an object graph with a lot of dependencies between objects I would think twice about this approach. If it fits with what you currently have defined though for object dependencies and creation policies by all means go for it.

Comment: Actually that's not much of an issue. The objects are really simple and if they contain reference to another object they do so with the object's ID. I've tried one object and now arises the issue of how to receive the object from the server, I'll update the question.